# What type of logic allows nested/self referential predicates, if any?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is there any logic system where the following is valid?

```
∀x∀y (y(x) → isPredicate(y))
isPredicate(isPredicate)
```

It seems like it would be useful to talk about predicates of predicates but I haven't seen any usage of self referential predicates in this manner and it might be invalid?